# Push notification Error with Parse

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, task

**Situation**

I've implemented push notification with Parse in **ANDROID**. Everything works great (I can receive push/send etc.), the only thing is that when I install my application it happens this:

- if it is the first install ever on the device: no problem
- if it is not the first install (this means that the device has already made a PARSE/GCM registration) it generates this error:

**Error generated**

```
02-12 11:12:28.054  15564-15579/com.hoxell.hoxellbrowser E/ParseCommandCache﹕ Failed to run command.
com.parse.ParseException: at least one ID field (installationId,deviceToken) must be specified in this operation
        at com.parse.ParseCommand.onPostExecute(ParseCommand.java:404)
        at com.parse.ParseRequest$5.then(ParseRequest.java:342)
        at com.parse.ParseRequest$5.then(ParseRequest.java:339)
        at bolts.Task$10.run(Task.java:486)
        at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:97)
        at bolts.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:482)
        at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:358)
        at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:369)
        at bolts.Task$8.then(Task.java:415)
        at bolts.Task$8.then(Task.java:407)
        at bolts.Task$10.run(Task.java:486)
        at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:97)
        at bolts.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:482)
        at bolts.Task.access$200(Task.java:27)
        at bolts.Task$6.then(Task.java:351)
        at bolts.Task$6.then(Task.java:348)
        at bolts.Task.runContinuations(Task.java:515)
        at bolts.Task.access$600(Task.java:27)
        at bolts.Task$TaskCompletionSource.trySetResult(Task.java:570)
        at bolts.Task$TaskCompletionSource.setResult(Task.java:604)
        at bolts.Task$10$1.then(Task.java:498)
        at bolts.Task$10$1.then(Task.java:490)
        at bolts.Task$9.run(Task.java:453)
        at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:97)
        at bolts.Task.completeImmediately(Task.java:449)
        at bolts.Task.access$100(Task.java:27)
        at bolts.Task$5.then(Task.java:316)
        at bolts.Task$5.then(Task.java:313)
        at bolts.Task.runContinuations(Task.java:515)
        at bolts.Task.access$600(Task.java:27)
        at bolts.Task$TaskCompletionSource.trySetResult(Task.java:570)
        at bolts.Task$TaskCompletionSource.setResult(Task.java:604)
        at bolts.Task$10$1.then(Task.java:498)
        at bolts.Task$10$1.then(Task.java:490)
        at bolts.Task$9.run(Task.java:453)
        at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:97)
        at bolts.Task.completeImmediately(Task.java:449)
        at bolts.Task.access$100(Task.java:27)
        at bolts.Task$5.then(Task.java:316)
        at bolts.Task$5.then(Task.java:313)
        at bolts.Task.runContinuations(Task.java:515)
        at bolts.Task.access$600(Task.java:27)
        at bolts.Task$TaskCompletionSource.trySetResult(Task.java:570)
        at bolts.Task$TaskCompletionSource.setResult(Task.java:604)
        at bolts.Task$10$1.then(Task.java:498)
        at bolts.Task$10$1.then(Task.java:490)
        at bolts.Task$9.run(Task.java:453)
        at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:97)
        at bolts.Task.completeImmediately(Task.java:449)
        at bolts.Task.continueWith(Task.java:323)
        at bolts.Task.continueWith(Task.java:334)
        at bolts.Task$10.run(Task.java:490)
        at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:97)
        at bolts.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:482)
        at bolts.Task.access$200(Task.java:27)
        at bolts.Task$6.then(Task.java:351)
        at bolts.Task$6.then(Task.java:348)
        at bolts.Task.runContinuations(Task.java:515)
        at bolts.Task.access$600(Task.java:27)
        at bolts.Task$TaskCompletionSource.trySetResult(Task.java:570)
        at bolts.Task$TaskCompletionSource.setResult(Task.java:604)
        at bolts.Task$10$1.then(Task.java:498)
        at bolts.Task$10$1.then(Task.java:490)
        at bolts.Task$9.run(Task.java:453)
        at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:97)
        at bolts.Task.completeImmediately(Task.java:449)
        at bolts.Task.continueWith(Task.java:323)
        at bolts.Task.continueWith(Task.java:334)
        at bolts.Task$10.run(Task.java:490)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
```

**Yeah, it generates it but the app do not crash! and the app still works: push notifications too, but you can understand that this is not 100% reliable.**

```
E/ParseCommandCache﹕ Failed to run command.
com.parse.ParseException: at least one ID field (installationId,deviceToken) must be specified in this operation
```

What does he want..? What should I do? What is the cause of the problem? Here is my code:

**Application.java**

```
 @Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    // Initialize the Parse SDK.
    Parse.initialize(this, "x", "x");

    // Specify an Activity to handle all pushes by default.
    PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, MainActivity.class);

    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();

}
```

In my mainActivity I just concatenate the deviceToken (in my case it is the installationId) into my userAgent: and this work fine too! Even if the error is generated, the installationID is inserted into the userAgent.

**MainActivity.java**

```
 deviceToken = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().getInstallationId();
 webSettings.setUserAgentString(userAgent + " ||" + deviceToken);
```

Am I making any mistakes into my code?

**Thank you**

Comment: As I recall, you do not need to save the installation when using setDefaultPushCallback. Try removing the saving of installation and see if it still happens.

Comment: @cYrixmorten I've deleted it and it seems like it works. But tell me, isn't the saveInBackground fundamental to make Parse work?

Comment: The thing is that setDefaultPushCallback will automatically save the installation for you. Cannot remember where I found it, but at some forum it was told to be the behavior. I guess a second save right after (without the first yet completed) brings the installation in a bad state, causing the non-fatal error msg.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following below:

```
 ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground(new SaveCallback()
    {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e)
        {
            PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(Application.this, MainActivit.class);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

As I recall, you do not need to save the installation when using setDefaultPushCallback. Try removing the saving of installation and see if it still happens.

setDefaultPushCallback will automatically save the installation for you. Cannot remember where I found it, but at some forum it was told to be the behavior. I guess a second save right after (without the first yet completed) brings the installation in a bad state, causing the non-fatal error msg.